# Problems with iostream library and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, iostream

I have tried to compile many times a small C++ program but it fails everytime I used gcc to compile.

I'm using Cygwin64 and this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 100

using namespace std;

#define MAX 100

int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Caantidad de elementos a ingresar";
    cin>>n;
     if(n<=0) {
        cout<<"Elementos ingresador no válidos"<<endl;
     } if(n>MAX) {
        cout<<"La cantidad ingresada no es válida, Maximo "<<MAX<<" : " <<endl;
        return n;        
     }

}
```

And the error is:

> $ gcc nuevo.cpp /tmp/ccurFCPF.o:nuevo.cpp:(.text+0x1c): referencia a
>   `std::basic_ostream >& std::operator<<
>    > std::basic_ostream >&, char const*)' sin definir

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Please post error code directly as text, not as a figure. If it's too long you can just post the beginning of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `gcc`, use `g++`. `gcc` is to be used for C programs. `g++` is to be used for C++ programs.

Comment: Good eyes! Never have spotted that in the figure.

Comment: @vsoftco, doesn't work always. For some reason, it worked this time :)

Comment: So simple but difficult to see sometimes, thank you!

Comment: Well, g++ is a helper.  It calls gcc, but passes all the arguments necessary for C++ code (including where to find C++ headers and C++ libraries).  So while this is the answer, it is **possible** for gcc to compile C++ code, with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: @MaxLybbert:: Not really. g++ is a wrapper in the same way that gcc is a wrapper used to invoke the back end of GCC. One is used to compiler C++ the other is used to compile C. They also have different behavior on how they handle files with different extensions and other idiosyncrasy when invoking different parts of the compilation processes.

Comment: The reason for my comment is that GCC documentation will tell you that gcc will compile the correct language as long as you use sane file extensions ( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-G_002b_002b.html ).  It doesn't take long for people to realize this is misleading -- since GCC only figures out which language is being compiled and ignores other things like header files and libraries that need to be linked in -- but beginners haven't yet learned that lesson.  I may not have been clear in my original comment, but I agree that calling g++ is the easiest route to go.